# MongoId - uninitialized constant App::Mongo (NameError)"

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems, sinatra

In Sinatra app I have

```
 #config.rb
  require 'mongoid'

  class App
    configure do 
        Mongoid.configure do |config|
          name = "my_db"
          host = "localhost"
          config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db(name)
          config.slaves = [Mongo::Connection.new(host, 27017, :slave_ok => true).db(name)]
          config.persist_in_safe_mode = false
        end
      end
    end

    #Gemfile
    gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0"
    gem "bson_ext"
```

and it gives me an error "`const_missing': uninitialized constant App::Mongo (NameError)"
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Mongoid 3.x no longer uses the 10Gen Ruby driver so `Mongo` module will not be loaded by `require 'mongoid'`.  You need to use the new `Mongoid.load!` method.  You may have to change your config.yml file a bit as the syntax has changed.  Please see http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html