# mongoid uninitialized constant CarrierDomain (NameError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

I found [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271365/mongoid-uninitialized-constant-appmongo-nameerror) and think I'm following the referenced directions from [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) but am still coming across this error.

As per the [instructions](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) I'm calling `Mongoid.load!("path/to/your/mongoid.yml")` in my ruby script, so I don't think it's that.

Maybe, as per the error message coming from `inflector`, it's an issue with how I'm defining CarrierDomain.  I'm referencing a rails model from the Sinatra script.  It's in a model file called carrier_domain.rb and the class is defined as CarrierDomain (`class CarrierDomain`).  In fact, here is the entire class definition (it's a little one):

```
class CarrierDomain
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :carrier
  field :country
  field :name
  field :prefix, default: ''
end
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
/Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant CarrierDomain (NameError)
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/metadata.rb:606:in `klass'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/builder.rb:39:in `klass'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/embedded/many.rb:25:in `block in build'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/embedded/many.rb:23:in `each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/embedded/many.rb:23:in `build'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:43:in `create_relation'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `__build__'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:156:in `block (3 levels) in getter'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:125:in `_loading'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:156:in `block (2 levels) in getter'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:84:in `_building'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:155:in `block in getter'
    from /opt/cmf/app/models/carrier.rb:120:in `to_email_addresses'
    from mta_connector.rb:151:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:645:in `yield_document'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/query.rb:78:in `block in each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/cursor.rb:26:in `block in each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/cursor.rb:26:in `each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/cursor.rb:26:in `each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/query.rb:77:in `each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/moped-1.2.7/lib/moped/query.rb:77:in `each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:133:in `block in each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:604:in `selecting'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:132:in `each'
    from /Users/arigold/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.10/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:18:in `each'
    from mta_connector.rb:139:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly require 'carrier_domain' in my Sinatra script.

I had thought that it would know to get the file, since it worked in the rails console (that is, I didn't need to require it in the rails console).  Hmm.

Anyhoo, adding `require 'carrier_domain'` (i.e. the uninitialized constant) to my Sinatra script worked.